# Getting email address from a field in Gmail

Tags: javascript, email, xpath, gmail, document.evaluate

When user opens email in Gmail, I need to take the email address from email field.

It's one of inputs for my API, but I have trouble targeting that field because Gmail has complex structure of page,

I have tried with `document.evaluate()` but it returns huge `XPathResult` object and I don’t know where email is stored.

```js
var expr = "//*[@id=\":2y\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]"
    + "/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/h3/span[2]"
var titles = document.evaluate(expr, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
console.log(titles);
```

Comment: It's Full Contact API, link : https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/

Comment: You need to post the code which you’ve tried. Otherwise, nobody else will have any clue how to help you. If you tried with `document.evaluate() `, then post your code that you tried that with. Somebody can help you deal with processing the `XPathResult` (it’s just an array of nodes, so you just loop through it or iterate through it to get the nodes you need).

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is not enough to go on here to be able to help. At a minimum, we will need to see a relevant, but small part of the (correct!) XML with the email address. Otherwise the best thing we can do is tell you what that code does, which won't help you very much. Please read [mcve] for guidance.